# Runtime error arcpyy using fields[f].append(row.getValue(f))

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, null

I am trying to write a arcpy script that will turn off all NULL and empty fields.  The script runs for a while and then gives a run time error at fields[f].append(row.getValue(f)).  Below is the script.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/temp"
out_layer = "temp.lyr"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '*')[0] # need to find way to get list of layers there can be more than one data frame
listfields = []
thebadlist = []
for LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.isGroupLayer: 
        print "group print"
    elif LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.isFeatureLayer:
        fields = dict((f.name, []) for f in arcpy.ListFields(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff) if not f.required)

        rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff,"","","","")
        for row in rows:
            for f in fields.keys():
                fields[f].append(row.getValue(f))  #**the error happens here** 
                #print row.getValue(f)

        for field, values in fields.iteritems():
            #print field

            if  field == "Shape": 
                listfields.append(field)
            elif all(map(lambda s: s is None or not str(s).strip(), values)):
                thebadlist.append(field)
            else: 
                listfields.append(field)

        # LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'exampledata', df)[0]
        # fill in your desired fields to remain visible 

        desiredFields = listfields

        field_info = arcpy.Describe(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff).fieldInfo # I need this for field count


        for i in range(field_info.count):
            if field_info.getfieldname(i) not in desiredFields:
                if field_info.getfieldname(i) == "SHAPE":
                    field_info.setvisible(i, 'VISIBLE')
                elif field_info.getfieldname(i) == "Shape":
                    field_info.setvisible(i, 'VISIBLE')
                else:
                    field_info.setvisible(i, 'HIDDEN')


        arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, out_layer)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, 'temp_layer', '', '', field_info)
        refLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer('temp_layer')
        # rename the ref layer the same as your target layer
        refLyr.name = LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.name 
        lyrfile = "C:/temp/temp.lyr"
        print LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.name
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(refLyr, lyrfile)
        arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, refLyr, False)
        # mxd.save()  
        print 'cleaning up-' 
        if arcpy.Exists('temp_layer'):
            print '\'temp_layer\' still in memory...deleting now...'
        arcpy.Delete_management('temp_layer')
        print 'deleting obj refs...'
        del LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, refLyr,  fields
        print 'done.'
```

Comment: Would you consider using an arcpy.da search cursor? the old style cursor is a little buggy. Also there is a where clause that could limit your search.. use make feature layer '{} is not NULL'.format(f) should do it, then get count > 0 means there's values in the field, no need for a cursor; but only if you're working with geodatabase feature classes - shapefiles do not support null values.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to turn off fields that contain all Null or empty strings... I wouldn't do this with a cursor, as I said in my comment, I would use [MakeFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) with a `where_clause`:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '*')[0]  # need to find way to get list of layers there can be more than one data frame
                                                # read ListDataFrames : http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000001p000000

for LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.isGroupLayer: 
        print "group print"
    elif LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.isFeatureLayer:
        fields        = [f for f in arcpy.ListFields(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff) if not f.required]
        NotBlankCount = {} # a new, empty dictionary to store the count of not empty rows

        for ThisField in fields:
            # Only look for blank strings in string fields, otherwise you will get a SQL error
            if f.type == 'String':
                DefQ = "{0} IS NOT NULL AND TRIM( BOTH ' ',{0} ) <> '' ".format(ThisField.name.lower())
            else:
                # field should be numeric..
                DefQ = "{0} IS NOT NULL".format(ThisField.name.lower())
            # make a layer of all the not blank rows
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff,"ThisLayer",DefQ)
            # store the count of not blank rows in a dictionary
            NotBlankCount[ThisField.name.lower()] = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("ThisLayer").getOutput(0))
            # delete the created layer for neatness
            arcpy.Delete_management("ThisLayer")

        allFields     = [f.name.lower() for f in arcpy.ListFields(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff)]
        fieldRange    = range(len(allFields))                     # a range indexing the fields
        descObject    = arcpy.Describe(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff) # describe object, use to get shapefieldname
        field_info    = descObject.fieldInfo                      # I need this for field count

        # go through the dictionary and switch visible depending on count of features
        for i in fieldRange:
            ThisField = allFields[i] # the name of the field at this index, already lower case
            if ThisField == descObject.shapeFieldName.lower(): # comparison in lower case to avoid case mismatch false negative
                field_info.setvisible(i, 'VISIBLE')
            elif ThisField in NotBlankCount:
                if NotBlankCount[ThisField] == 0:
                    # no features returned for this field, make it hidden
                    print 'Hiding field {}'.format(ThisField)
                    field_info.setvisible(i, 'HIDDEN')
                else:
                    print 'Showing field {}'.format(ThisField)
                    field_info.setvisible(i, 'VISIBLE')
            else:       
                # field not in NotBlankCount, must be a required field      
                field_info.setvisible(i, 'VISIBLE')     

        arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, out_layer)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, 'temp_layer', '', '', field_info)
        refLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer('temp_layer')
        # rename the ref layer the same as your target layer
        refLyr.name = LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.name 
        lyrfile     = arcpy.env.workspace + '\\' + out_layer
        print LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff.name
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(refLyr, lyrfile)
        arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, refLyr, False)
        # mxd.save()  
        print 'cleaning up-' 
        if arcpy.Exists('temp_layer'):
            print '\'temp_layer\' still in memory...deleting now...'
            arcpy.Delete_management('temp_layer')
        print 'deleting obj refs...'
        del LayerNeedsFieldsTurnedOff, refLyr,  fields
        print 'done.'
```

You have a comment about finding all your data frames in this map document, this can be done with [ListDataFrames](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000001p000000).